# Locus of a point and family of lines

Tags: coordinate-systems

If the family of lines  $ax+3y-6=0 $ (a is a variable) intersect the lines $x-2y+3=0$  and  & $x-y+1=0$  at P and Q respectively, then the locus of the mid point of P and Q is?r

My attempt :
Solving $x-2y+3=0$ and $ ax+3y-6=0$, I got $$ P= (\frac {3}{3+2a},\frac{6+3a}{3+2a}) $$.
Solving $x-y+1=0$ and $ax+3y-6=0 $, I got $$ Q= (\frac {3}{3+a},\frac{6+a}{3+a}) $$.
How do I eliminate a from these equations?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
Find Midpoint of P and Q = $(M_x,M_y) = (x,y)$,

Now $M_x = x$, solve a in terms of x

and put a in terms of x in $M_y = y$

Comment: I did that but the terms could not be simplified and there were terms of x³ involved which wasn't there in the answer